# How to display unknown amount of images on web app?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display images using html, css, and javascript (I don't know if all three are necessary). I picture them in a grid sort of way. However, I don't want them to be in a table with strict lines. I don't know the number of images as I'm grabbing them from an API and inserting them into the website. I'm stuck and haven't really found anything yet on the web. If you have any suggestions I'd appreciate your input. Thanks!

Comment: Share code, or atleast something that you've done

Comment: Could you start by providing an example of how you are getting the images from the API and maybe give some sort of example of your expected output?

Comment: Use combination of css grid and javascript

Comment: I'm sorry I haven't really coded anything yet I just don't know where to start :( I'm getting the images from an API calls and then receive the urls. One url I would receive for example is like this: https://api.nasa.gov/EPIC/archive/natural/2015/06/13/png/epic_1b_20150613110250.png?api_key=DEMO_KEY

Comment: @brk what do you mean by css grid and javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Try to guess, what do you want without any examples of code. 
Appreciate such people it is free XD

```
.img-container{
    width:100%;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}

img {
    width:100px;
    max-width:200px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That actually has to do something with how I wanted to format the images. I didn't want them to be static in a table. I wanted them to resize according to the window. I'll search more about flex.

Comment: @T.Doe you're welcome